# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8000

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created the WCF service and trying to host in Managed Windows Service (followed [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)). The service is up and running in services.

When trying to add the URL in the client application (net.tcp://localhost:8000/UserManagement) I get the error:

> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'net.tcp://localhost:8000/UserManagement'. Could not connect to
>   net.tcp://localhost:8000/UserManagement. The connection attempt lasted
>   for a time span of 00:00:00.9531433. TCP error code 10061: No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it 127.0.0.1:8000.  No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8000 If the service is defined
>   in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the
>   service reference again.

**Service.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Configuration.Install;

namespace AddUser
{
public class UserManagement : IUserManagement
{

    public bool AddUser(string strName, DateTime dtDOB, string strGender, string strRole)
    {

        return true;
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IUserManagement
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool AddUser(string strLname,string strFName, string strUname, string strPswd, DateTime dtDOB, string strGender, string strRole, string strHobbies);

}

public class UserManagementService : ServiceBase
{
    public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
    public UserManagementService()
    {
        ServiceName = "WCFUserManagementService";
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new UserManagementService());
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
        }                        
        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(UserManagementService));
        serviceHost.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
            serviceHost = null;
        }
    }
}

[RunInstaller(true)]
public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
    private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
    private ServiceInstaller service;

    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        service = new ServiceInstaller();
        service.ServiceName = "WCFUserManagementService";
        Installers.Add(process);
        Installers.Add(service);
    }
}

}
```

**app.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="AddUser.UserManagementServiceBehavior" name="AddUser.UserManagement">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="AddUser.IUserManagement"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
        <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8000/UserManagement" />
        </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="AddUser.UserManagementServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: shouldn't baseAddress be http://localhost:8000/ like in the example

Comment: i tried even with localhost:8000 still not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the address

```
net.tcp://localhost:8000/UserManagement/mex
```

when you are configuring your service reference.

Alternatively your metadata endpoint should use the `mexHttpBinding` and you should set your `httpGetEnabled` to true in your service behavior

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue after following MSDN link you provided. There is a error in that code.

In you OnStart method,

```
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(UserManagementService));
```

instead of creating ServiceHost for UserManagementService, use your actual WCF service class name here. This line of code will create an instance of windows service and not the WCF service. I was able to fix mine using that.